# How to check whether server IP status is up or down in PHP

Tags: php, server, ip, ping, fsockopen

I am creating a web application where I will be adding 10-20 IP addresses and setting a cron job for every 1 hour, that can be done easily. The problem is that I want to check whether an IP is currently working or not. If the IP is not working then I will get a message by email or some other mode. I have found the below code on the Internet:

```
$ip= '103.117.231.160';
$port = 80;
$fp = @fsockopen($ip, $port, $errno, $errstr, 2);
if (!$fp) {
   echo 'offline';
} else{ 
    echo 'online';
 }
```

I have added many random IPs, but it's giving me online for the status. Is the above script fine or do I need to change the script? How can I test that an IP is working or not? Can anyone provide sample test IPs so I can make sure the script is working fine?

I just need correct output via email that my server is down.

Comment: seems to work ok. Google reported `online` unsurprisingly and the ip in the question says `offline`

Comment: @RamRaider now what can i do?

Comment: whenever i will saving ip address in database i need to collect correct port as well?

Comment: Depend on what you gonna do with the IP. You are currently just testing port 80 and if that is all you need then you don't need to collect the port, but if you want to test multiple ports then probably you should store which port is working with that IP.

Comment: Port 80 just checks for the http service. Of course if it answers, the server is online. But it checks only that service! What about using the good old ping?

Comment: @catcon thanks for your reply. I am just concern about the script that is fine or not.... port i will be saved in database as well,,, My only concren about output.. Suppose now time is 12.53pm and Server goes down (103.117.231.160) and i must notify at 13:53 that srever is down and after server is again up and i must notify again after 1 hour that server is working now... Is that script is ok to live?

Comment: @MarkusZeller I have tried Ping too but i am not sure this give me accurate results..  exec('ping 103.117.231.160')  but how can i verify srever is working or not

Comment: @MarkusZeller if you better way to do ,, i am open to change my script. Noted :- but it must be working

Comment: I'd use a simple solution like [ping](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.networking.net-ping.ping.php).

Comment: You have not clearly defined what you consider to be a "working" IP address.

Comment: $ping->ping('example.com') but this is using url i need to do with IP

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Suppose i have this IP 103.117.231.160 and this IP is linked to some website or anything and after some time its goes down and i get notification  and later on it will work again

Comment: string $host - the name of the server or the IP-adress

Comment: @frz3993 IP address

Comment: I mean I literally copied that directly from the link @MarkusZeller gave you.

Comment: Clearly defining something means avoiding wording like "or anything". If you just want to check whether a website works or not you can try to download a page. If it downloads the site is up, otherwise it is down. Note that an IP address might be "working" (depending on how you test this) even when the website doesn't.

Comment: No i my client wants to test with IP only

Comment: Then use Ping! It checks, if the IP address responds. If the network responds, it is online. Simple as that.

Comment: If you want to test a specific service, you have to connect to it (example: http, mail, dns)